# Ошибка $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated

Tags: php

Возникает эта ошибка (файл error_log в корне сайта, виртуальный хостинг):

> PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this
>   warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use
>   the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

В [документации написано](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)  использовать `php://input` вместо `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, но у меня в скрипте используется код согласно документации. Нет никакого `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`.

```
$report = file_get_contents('php://input');
$report = json_decode($report, true);
```

Где ошибка в коде? Как исправить? Доступа к php.ini сервера естественно нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка не за использование этой переменной, а возникает из-за самого факта создания этой переменной ядром PHP, т.е. некорректной настройки.

Через ini_set фактически настройку изменить можно, но слишком поздно - ошибка генерируется до вызова ini_set. Если у вас нет доступа к php.ini - значит пинайте техподдержку. А так же можно попробовать изменить настройки через [`.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38390004) (если опять же разрешено рутом):

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data -1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло, другие флаги работают (друпал движок на этом же хостинге)

Answer (score 3):

Только что попробовал

```
$report = file_get_contents('php://input');
$report = json_decode($report, true);
var_dump($report);
```

Вывод - `NULL`

Ошибок нет

---

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261001/warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated) пишут, что надо поменять параметр в `php.ini`. Если нет к нему доступа, [попробуйте](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ini-set.php) поменять во время выполнения

```
    ini_set('always_populate_raw_post_data','-1');
```

Comment: в том скрипте `$report` соединяется в строку и записываю в файл `file_put_contents('report.csv', $csvLine, FILE_APPEND);` вот и все, может ли эта строка вызывать ошибку? (file_put_contents())

Comment: Вряд ли, это не файловая ошибка. Дописал ответ - обратите внимание

Comment: не помогло......

Answer (score 0):

Если доступа к **php.ini** нет и **.htaccess** нельзя переопределить. Как это произошло у меня.
Можно зайти с другой стороны. С фронта поменять в запросе **Content-Type** на `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
А на бэке уже словить и распарсить `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)`

Comment: пасиб, тот скрипт уже не использую.