# считать json на php

Tags: php, json

делаю следующее:

```
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postData, true);
```

Сервер возвращает:

```
Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
```

как убрать это сообщение? досупа к php.ini и к .htaccess не имею вообще.
изменил код на

```
$file = fopen('php://input', "r");
$postData = fgets($file);
fclose($file);
$data = json_decode($postData, true);
```

возвращает тоже самое. как избавиться от этого злосчастного php://input??

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка $HTTP\_RAW\_POST\_DATA is deprecated](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655831/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-http-raw-post-data-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Если нет доступа к ini, то попробуйте в скрипте поменять значение при выполнении с помощью: `ini_set('always_populate_raw_post_data','-1');`

Comment: это тоже не помогает, пытался

Answer (score 0):

помог откат на раннюю версию php. на этом хостинге ничего другого не получилось